# How do I use the Android Accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I'm trying to build an app for reading the values from the accelerometer on my phone, which supports Android 2.1 only.

How do I read from the accelerometer using 2.1-compatible code?

Comment: a ball game project uses accelerometer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188957/Simple-Android-Ball-Game

Comment: take a look at http://onetouchcode.com/2016/08/07/android-accelerometer-example/

Answer (score 53):

Start with this:

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
 private SensorManager sensorManager;
 double ax,ay,az;   // these are the acceleration in x,y and z axis
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
   }
   @Override
   public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
            ax=event.values[0];
                    ay=event.values[1];
                    az=event.values[2];
            }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

This isn't easily explained in a few paragraphs. You should try to read:

- [Sensor Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)
- [`SensorManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) description

These show a framework on how to access sensors:

```
 public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
     private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
     private final Sensor mAccelerometer;

     public SensorActivity() {
         mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
         mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
     }

     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
     }

     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
     }

     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
     }

     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
     }
 }
```

In the `onSensorChanged` callback you can query the sensor's values through the [`SensorEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html).

Comment: The server on AndroGames doesn't seem to exist anymore, and the AndDev link is from 2008 = horribly old. The other suggestions are good though.

Comment: Ah, well it's been a while since I've posted that answer. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: I would recommend to remove any reference to AndDev website -it is sending high-severity cyber attack intercepted by Norton. Thanks for the understanding. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell I can't verify your claim, but anyway, it's a post from 2008, so I removed those links.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Best regards,

Answer (score 7):

A very good example for accelerometer app.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

Comment: Working link: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/ [edit queue is full or I'd submit it as such]