# Displaying Accelerometer Values in Android

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am looking for some source code or example code detailing how to display the values of the accelerometer in Android. Preferably, the values would show acceleration in the x direction, y direction, and z direction.

I am an Android noob so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Potential exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180187/android-accelerometer

Comment: one of the links is outdated, the other is just too complicated for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you checked out the [Accelerometer example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/index.html) in the android samples? You could always try something like this (which I got from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)):

```
 public class SensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
     private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
     private final Sensor mAccelerometer;

     public SensorActivity() {
         mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
         mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
     }

     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
     }

     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
     }

     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
     }

     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       //Right in here is where you put code to read the current sensor values and 
       //update any views you might have that are displaying the sensor information
       //You'd get accelerometer values like this:
       if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            return;
        float mSensorX, mSensorY;
        switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                mSensorX = event.values[0];
                mSensorY = event.values[1];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                mSensorX = -event.values[1];
                mSensorY = event.values[0];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                mSensorX = -event.values[0];
                mSensorY = -event.values[1];
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                mSensorX = event.values[1];
                mSensorY = -event.values[0];
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to use that information to display basic accelerometer values.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: I see, but in the commented section, what exactly do I need to put in to read the values?

Comment: I lifted some code directly from the android accelerometer example and put it in my answer.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum From where you get the mDisplay.getRotation() ??

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585 please checkout the example I linked to

Comment: For those who are looking for `getRotation`, use this
`Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example with gravitation, this will return the vector of gravity. Note that you can change the sensor type and the speed of sampling, more details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html)

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        double total = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

}, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```