# how to start make app like clinometer in android

Tags: android, accelerometer, tilt-sensor

i want to get and move needle on co-ordinates as per user rotates or move device as compass does also as this app is doing already.you can see what i want to say on this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plaincode.clinometer&hl=en but now at this time i am not able to understand on this context. i am unable to find hint for how to start..is their is any api to get and make it work or need to implement accelerometer on a very extensive level to get it done. please guide me if u have any code or link regarding this..thank in advance

Comment: It looks like you don't have a clue where to start, try searching StackOverflow on 'accelerometer'. That gives this duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180187/how-do-i-use-the-android-accelerometer

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this solution more than a year ago and for that somehow i managed to do this similar this way. and source for that which i managed to do is -- [link to source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C9Pqrvc_CWZVNPdENvWm9nSXM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you able to replicate the behavior of that app ?

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You should start creating an activity that implements SensorEventListener, including the two following methods:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        // add your code
        // event.values[] contains the 3 accelerometer values
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    // add your code
}
```

As second step, start with the implementation of accelerometers into the Activity:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mRotationSensor;
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

Then register a sensor listener on it (you could do in onResume):

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mRotationSensor, 16000);
// 16000 microseconds
```

and unregister it (in onPause):

```
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
```

Please note that, if you want a very accurate measurement of angles and slopes in the 3 dimensions, you should implement a calibration routine of the onboard accelerometers, that usually need a small compensation in **gain**, **offset** and **angle**.

You can read a simple but complete usage of Accelerometers on the free and opensource BasicAirData Clinometer: https://github.com/BasicAirData/Clinometer

The app includes also a calibration routine.