# How to make a picture keel over using the accelerometer?

Tags: android, 2d, physics

I want to add a method to my app that makes a picture keel over when you move the phone left or right. I know how to use the main functions of the accelerometer but in this case I got some problems. It would also help to send a link to an easy toutorial!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does keel over mean, exactly, in non-nautical terms?

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry... I don't quite speak english fluently... I mean that it should "fall down" to one side..

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180187/how-do-i-use-the-android-accelerometer and here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/