# Android screen - angle of rotation

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-orientation

Question is related to rotation of the android emulator screen.

I am using `DefaultDisplay.getRotation()` to get the rotation angle on the emulator. It returns 0 and 90 only. Even in reverse portrait and reverse landscape. Have not set any specific Screen orientation in the activity XML file. I am a beginner at this so am probably missing something here and could use some help understanding what that might be.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the Android Accelerometer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180187/how-do-i-use-the-android-accelerometer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `getRotation` method doesn't work in emulator screen. Because according to your thread you can see you are getting only two angles i.e. "0" and "90" because of **landscape** and **potrait mode**. So just test it in any real device.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Log.v("rotation--", ""+rotation);

        switch (rotation) {

        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Angle 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Angle 90", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Angle 180", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case 3:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Angle 270", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to portrait/reverse portrait and landscape/reverse landscape you can use

```
            if (Utils.getDeviceDefaultOrientation(localActivity) == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {
                if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
                    //Landscape Mode
                else if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
                    //Portrait Mode
                else if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
                    //Reverse Landscape
                else if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
                    //Reverse Portrait
            }
            else
            {
                if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
                    //Portrait Mode
                else if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
                    //Landscape Mode
                else if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
                    //Reverse Portrait Mode
                else if (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
                    //Reverse Landscape Mode
            }
```

We have to check for `getDeviceDefaultOrientation` because for tablets the default device orientation is Landscape and it will return `getRotation()` 0 in that case