# Getting orientation for an activity

Tags: android, android-orientation

I need to get the orientation of a device. The screen orientation of the device is fixed as portrait.I have used the following code but it doesn't seem to work.I have made changes in the manifest file

due to which
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
always gives the same value

```
public final class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,SensorEventListener{

  private static final String TAG = CaptureActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  private static final long DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS = 1500L;
  private static final long BULK_MODE_SCAN_DELAY_MS = 1000L;

  private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
  private static final String PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_PREFIX = "http://www.google";
  private static final String PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_SUFFIX = "/m/products/scan";
  private static final String[] ZXING_URLS = { "http://zxing.appspot.com/scan", "zxing://scan/" };

  public static final int HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000bacc;

  private static final Set<ResultMetadataType> DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES =
      EnumSet.of(ResultMetadataType.ISSUE_NUMBER,
                 ResultMetadataType.SUGGESTED_PRICE,
                 ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL,
                 ResultMetadataType.POSSIBLE_COUNTRY);

  private CameraManager cameraManager;
  private CaptureActivityHandler handler;
  private Result savedResultToShow;
  private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;
  //private TextView statusView;
  //private View resultView;
  private Result lastResult;
  private boolean hasSurface;
  private boolean copyToClipboard;
  private IntentSource source;
  private String sourceUrl;
  private ScanFromWebPageManager scanFromWebPageManager;
  private Collection<BarcodeFormat> decodeFormats;
  private Map<DecodeHintType,?> decodeHints;
  private String characterSet;
  private HistoryManager historyManager;
  private InactivityTimer inactivityTimer;
  private BeepManager beepManager;
  private AmbientLightManager ambientLightManager;
  private int orientation;

  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private Sensor mAccelerometer;



  ViewfinderView getViewfinderView() {
    return viewfinderView;
  }

  public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
  }

  CameraManager getCameraManager() {
    return cameraManager;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.capture);





    hasSurface = false;
    historyManager = new HistoryManager(this);
    historyManager.trimHistory();
    inactivityTimer = new InactivityTimer(this);
    beepManager = new BeepManager(this);
    ambientLightManager = new AmbientLightManager(this);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

    //showHelpOnFirstLaunch();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // CameraManager must be initialized here, not in onCreate(). This is necessary because we don't
    // want to open the camera driver and measure the screen size if we're going to show the help on
    // first launch. That led to bugs where the scanning rectangle was the wrong size and partially
    // off screen.
    cameraManager = new CameraManager(getApplication());

    viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView) findViewById(R.id.viewfinder_view);
    viewfinderView.setCameraManager(cameraManager);


    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);






    Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientaionWidth = display.getWidth();
    int orientaionHeight = display.getHeight();
    int rotation=display.getRotation();


    int orien=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    boolean orientation = false;
    if(orientaionWidth>orientaionHeight){

        orientation=true;
    }


    if(orien==1){       

         setLandscape(true);

    }else{
        setLandscape(false);
    }
    handler = null;
    lastResult = null;

    resetStatusView();

    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    if (hasSurface) {
      // The activity was paused but not stopped, so the surface still exists. Therefore
      // surfaceCreated() won't be called, so init the camera here.
      initCamera(surfaceHolder);
    } else {
      // Install the callback and wait for surfaceCreated() to init the camera.
      surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
      surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    beepManager.updatePrefs();
    ambientLightManager.start(cameraManager);

    inactivityTimer.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    copyToClipboard = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_COPY_TO_CLIPBOARD, true)
        && (intent == null || intent.getBooleanExtra(Intents.Scan.SAVE_HISTORY, true));

    source = IntentSource.NONE;
    decodeFormats = null;
    characterSet = null;

    if (intent != null) {

      String action = intent.getAction();
      String dataString = intent.getDataString();

      if (Intents.Scan.ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // Scan the formats the intent requested, and return the result to the calling activity.
        source = IntentSource.NATIVE_APP_INTENT;
        decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.parseDecodeFormats(intent);
        decodeHints = DecodeHintManager.parseDecodeHints(intent);

        if (intent.hasExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH) && intent.hasExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT)) {
          int width = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH, 0);
          int height = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT, 0);
          if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            cameraManager.setManualFramingRect(width, height);
          }
        }

        String customPromptMessage = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.PROMPT_MESSAGE);


      } else if (dataString != null &&
                 dataString.contains(PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_PREFIX) &&
                 dataString.contains(PRODUCT_SEARCH_URL_SUFFIX)) {

        // Scan only products and send the result to mobile Product Search.
        source = IntentSource.PRODUCT_SEARCH_LINK;
        sourceUrl = dataString;
        decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.PRODUCT_FORMATS;

      } else if (isZXingURL(dataString)) {

        // Scan formats requested in query string (all formats if none specified).
        // If a return URL is specified, send the results there. Otherwise, handle it ourselves.
        source = IntentSource.ZXING_LINK;
        sourceUrl = dataString;
        Uri inputUri = Uri.parse(dataString);
        scanFromWebPageManager = new ScanFromWebPageManager(inputUri);
        decodeFormats = DecodeFormatManager.parseDecodeFormats(inputUri);
        // Allow a sub-set of the hints to be specified by the caller.
        decodeHints = DecodeHintManager.parseDecodeHints(inputUri);

      }

      characterSet = intent.getStringExtra(Intents.Scan.CHARACTER_SET);

    }
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    if (handler != null) {
      handler.quitSynchronously();
      handler = null;
    }
    inactivityTimer.onPause();
    ambientLightManager.stop();
    cameraManager.closeDriver();
    if (!hasSurface) {
      SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
      SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
      surfaceHolder.removeCallback(this);
    }
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    inactivityTimer.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
  }




  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode == HISTORY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        int itemNumber = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.History.ITEM_NUMBER, -1);
        if (itemNumber >= 0) {
          HistoryItem historyItem = historyManager.buildHistoryItem(itemNumber);
          decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, historyItem.getResult());
        }
      }
    }
  }


  @Override
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (holder == null) {
      Log.e(TAG, "*** WARNING *** surfaceCreated() gave us a null surface!");
    }
    if (!hasSurface) {
      hasSurface = true;
      initCamera(holder);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    hasSurface = false;
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

  }


  private static void drawLine(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, ResultPoint a, ResultPoint b, float scaleFactor) {
    if (a != null && b != null) {
      canvas.drawLine(scaleFactor * a.getX(), 
                      scaleFactor * a.getY(), 
                      scaleFactor * b.getX(), 
                      scaleFactor * b.getY(), 
                      paint);
    }
  }



  private void sendReplyMessage(int id, Object arg, long delayMS) {
    Message message = Message.obtain(handler, id, arg);
    if (delayMS > 0L) {
      handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, delayMS);
    } else {
      handler.sendMessage(message);
    }
  }

  /**
   * We want the help screen to be shown automatically the first time a new version of the app is
   * run. The easiest way to do this is to check android:versionCode from the manifest, and compare
   * it to a value stored as a preference.
   */
  private boolean showHelpOnFirstLaunch() {
   /* try {
      PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
      int currentVersion = info.versionCode;
      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      int lastVersion = prefs.getInt(PreferencesActivity.KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN, 0);
      if (currentVersion > lastVersion) {
        prefs.edit().putInt(PreferencesActivity.KEY_HELP_VERSION_SHOWN, currentVersion).commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        // Show the default page on a clean install, and the what's new page on an upgrade.
        String page = lastVersion == 0 ? HelpActivity.DEFAULT_PAGE : HelpActivity.WHATS_NEW_PAGE;
        intent.putExtra(HelpActivity.REQUESTED_PAGE_KEY, page);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
      }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      Log.w(TAG, e);
    }*/
    return false;
  }

  private void initCamera(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    if (surfaceHolder == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("No SurfaceHolder provided");
    }
    if (cameraManager.isOpen()) {
      Log.w(TAG, "initCamera() while already open -- late SurfaceView callback?");
      return;
    }
    try {
      cameraManager.openDriver(surfaceHolder);
      // Creating the handler starts the preview, which can also throw a RuntimeException.
      if (handler == null) {
        handler = new CaptureActivityHandler(this, decodeFormats, decodeHints, characterSet, cameraManager);
      }
      decodeOrStoreSavedBitmap(null, null);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      Log.w(TAG, ioe);
      displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      // Barcode Scanner has seen crashes in the wild of this variety:
      // java.?lang.?RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
      Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected error initializing camera", e);
      displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit();
    }
  }

  private void displayFrameworkBugMessageAndExit() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_camera_framework_bug));
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new FinishListener(this));
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new FinishListener(this));
    builder.show();
  }

  public void restartPreviewAfterDelay(long delayMS) {
    if (handler != null) {
      handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(R.id.restart_preview, delayMS);
    }
    resetStatusView();
  }

  private void resetStatusView() {
    viewfinderView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lastResult = null;
  }

  public void drawViewfinder() {
    viewfinderView.drawViewfinder();
  }

  @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {


      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
  public void setLandscape(boolean orientation) {
        viewfinderView.setLandscape(orientation);
      }

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.values[1]<6.5 && arg0.values[1]>-6.5) {
        if (orientation!=1) {
            Log.d("Sensor", "Landscape");
        }
        orientation=1;
    } else {
        if (orientation!=0) {
            Log.d("Sensor", "Portrait");
        }
        orientation=0;
    }


}

}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663665/how-can-i-get-the-current-screen-orientation

Comment: use `Activity.getResources()`

Comment: i have already mentioned thatgetResources().getConfiguration().orientation,doesnt work if the screen orientaion is fixed in the manifest file.please read the question before marking it as duplicate.

Comment: That doesnt work either, cannot make a static call to a non static method

Comment: Hi @ling.s Activity.getresource() doesnt work either

Comment: Ok i am posting the whole activity code, though i dont think it would make any difference

Comment: still you are using `int orien=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;` please change according to Arju's answer

Comment: The error is getResources().getConfiguration().orientation always gives the value as 1 which is potrait mode.Even when i turn the phone in landscape mode

Comment: hi @ling.s I think when he meant Activity.getResource he meant the Activity from where the method is called because Activity.getResource is a static call to a non static method, you can try it if you would like

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current orientation through

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

or

```
getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

Comment: i have already mentioned that getResources().getConfiguration().orientation,doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

this should work...

```
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Portrait");
    } else if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Log.i(TAG, "LandScape");
    }
```

Comment: i have already mentioned that getResources().getConfiguration().orientation,doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

/* Now we can retrieve all display-related infos */
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

Also, try with `Activity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`

Comment: Hi, Activity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation wont work, there is no method called Activity().I tried with what you said Still get the same orientation value

Comment: Can you please answer the question.Since you have marked it as duplicate no one else is going to.

Comment: still waiting for an answer

Answer (score 0):

By setting the orientation to be fixed to portrait in the manifest, you cant use  getResources().getConfiguration().orientation as you already know.

Try using the accelerometer to determine the current rotation/tilt of the device as described here, [How do I use the Android Accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180187/how-do-i-use-the-android-accelerometer)